# Addition of two binaries numbers in Python

Tags: python

Hey guys i have a trouble when i want to add two binaries numbers in Python, i mean i can enter a chain of character in a form of a string but i don't know how to select a specific value in the chain. Here is my code:

```
chaina = input('Enter your first binary number')
chainb = input('Enter your second binary number')
liste = str()
r = 0
for i in range [-1,chaina]:
   t = 0
   t = chaina() + chainb() + r
if t == 2 :
    r = 1
    liste = str(t) + liste            
elif t == 0 or t == 1:
     r = 0
     liste = str(t) + liste
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: `str is not callable`...? What are you expecting to happen from `chaina()`?

Comment: It's my first Binarie number,i expect that the program will go from the first to the lath term of the chain

Comment: Also, `range [-1,chaina]` is not valid Python. What would you like to accomplish by this?

Comment: I would like that the first term of chaina is added with the first term of chainb etc until the last term following the rule of addition in base 2

Comment: `chaina` and `chainb` are string variables, not functions. You cannot call a variable. Besides, t can never become "2" if two strings are added. str(1) + str(1) = "11".

Comment: Are you sure that you want to add them? It sounds as if you would simply need  one of the binary operators. What do you expect as result if one specific digit in number a is "1" and "1" in number b? Not two I guess....

Comment: What i mean is that if i want to add 1010 and 1111 i would give 11001 i don't want to convert them in base 10

Comment: @Diamonddeo: If any of the provided answers helped you solve the problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

To add two binary numbers `chaina` and `chainb`:

```
bin(eval('0b{} + 0b{}'.format(chaina, chainb)))
```

Or, if you want the binary number without the leading `'0b'`:

```
format(eval('0b{} + 0b{}'.format(chaina, chainb)), 'b')
```

### Explanation

Assume for illustration that `chaina = '1010'` and `chainb = '1111'`. Then:

```
>>> '0b{} + 0b{}'.format(chaina, chainb)
'0b1010 + 0b1111'
```

By applying `eval()` on this string, we get the same result as if we typed the expression `0b1010 + 0b1111` directly into Python console.

```
>>> 0b1010 + 0b1111
25
>>> eval('0b1010 + 0b1111')
25
```

Finally, `bin()` produces a binary representation of the number passed to it as an argument:

```
>>> bin(25)
'0b11001'
```

The same thing is accomplished by calling `format()` with a `'b'` argument:

```
>>> format(25, 'b')
'11001'
```

All put together, we are getting the expressions shown above.

Comment: Hey i have some trouble to understand how this function, as i said it sooner i'm french so the communication is a bit complicated,could you explain it just a bit ?

Comment: Thank you for your help,  really

Comment: It's not me that have downvoted, i saw it and i upvoted to correct it but it wasn't me

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply convert them into decimal and add them as you would do with decimals:

```
y = '0b101010'
z = '0b101010'

print(int(y,2) + int(z,2))
print(bin((int(y,2) + int(z,2))))
```

Comment: hey thanks for you answer,it's a school project and i think that my teacher won't accept this

Comment: If there are restrictions as to which Python constructions can and cannot be used, please include them in the question.

Comment: It is pretty much unclear to me what @Diamonddeo is expecting as results

Comment: Sorry i'm french so it's a bit difficult to described what i want with precision, i would like to make an addition of 2 values in base 2 for exemple 1010 + 1111 would give 11001

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to do a binary sum *by hand*, you must:

- process both numbers starting from the end (`reversed` will help here)
- consistently add bits processing carry until the lengther of both numbers is exhausted
- reorder the result bits (here again `reversed`)

Code could be (assuming that you can be sure that `chaina` and `chainb` only consist in `0` and `1` characters, no test for it here):

```
def binsum(chaina, chainb):
    def next0(it):
        """Retrieve next digit from a binary representation, 0 when exhausted"""
        try:
            return int(next(it))
        except StopIteration:
            return 0
    a = reversed(chaina)  # reverse chains to start with lowest order bit
    b = reversed(chainb)
    r = 0
    result = []           # future result
    for i in range(n):
        t = next0(a) + next0(b) + r  # add with carry
        if t > 1:
            t -= 2
            r = 1
        else:
            r = 0
        result.append('1' if t else '0')
    if r != 0:                        # do not forget last carry
        result.append('1')
    return ''.join(result)
```

Comment: Thanks i will try this out

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions

1. normalize the lengths of the bit strings

   ```
   l0, l1 = map(len, (str0, str1))
   if l0 < l1:
       str0 = "0"*(l1-l0) + str0
   elif l1 < l0:
       str1 = "0"*(l0-l1) + str1
   ```
2. do a loop on the reversed strings elements and construct the binary string bottom up

   ```
   remainder = 0
   result = ""
   for bit_0, bit1 in zip(reversed(str0), reversed(str1)):
       bit_0, bit_1 = map(int, (bit_0, bit_1))
       new_bit, remainder = f(bit_0, bit_1, remainder)
       result = str(new_bit) + result
   if remainder != 0
       ...
   ```

writing `f(bit_0, bit_1, remainder)` and treating what to do if `remainder` is not null at the end of the loop is left as an exercise.